# Is it possible to get rid of lodash in Angular 4?

Tags: angular, lodash

Recently I found out that lodash is using over 500 KB in my Angular 4 application, after publish. I removed all lodash usages and removed its package.

But now i have a problem on build:

> Error: Cannot find module 'lodash'

Is lodash required in Angular? Can't it be removed?

**[Edit]**

I removed all dependencies, but I still can't start the app or build it.
However when I use:

```
npm install
```

The result is:

```
`-- @angular/cli@1.2.7
    `-- lodash@4.17.11
```

And then the app works, but it again has lodash, although it's not mentioned in package.json. It seems like angular-cli requires that...

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "agent-reporting-client",
  "version": "1.4.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run meta && ng serve -o --port 185 --host localdev.moneygram.com",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test -sm='false'",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "publish": "npm run meta && ng build --aot --prod --environment=prod",
    "debug-aot": "ng build --aot --environment=prod --output-hashing none",
    "meta": "node meta/build src src/metaDefinitions.ts"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "4.3.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "7.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "0.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "core-js": "2.4.1",
    "es5-shim": "4.5.9",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "file-saver": "1.3.3",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng2-webstorage": "1.8.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.5",
    "nodegit": "0.20.2",
    "oidc-client": "1.5.4",
    "rxjs": "5.4.3",
    "zone.js": "0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "4.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "3.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.3.3",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "0.4.6",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```

npm ls lodash:

```
+-- @angular/cli@1.2.7
| `-- lodash@4.17.11
+-- karma@1.7.0
| `-- lodash@3.10.1
`-- webpack-bundle-analyzer@3.0.3
  `-- lodash@4.17.11
```

Thanks for your help...

Comment: `lodash` is not required by Angular, you must still have some reference to it somewhere in the app

Comment: @bugs Ineed I had some left dependencies, that's why I panicked and deleted post, but... After removing those the problem is still there. I will update the post.

Comment: Can you add to the question your `package.json` file and the results of the command `npm ls lodash`?

Comment: @Vlad274 Updated

Comment: That is a very old angular-cli version :0

Comment: @EluciusFTW Year ago it was quite new :D Ok, so it seems I should try to update angular-cli... There is no lodash required on newer version, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because it's in the CLI doesn't mean it's in your compiled output.  The CLI is a tool.  That's why it's in devDependencies and not in dependencies in your package.json. It doesn't get compiled into the output of your Angular code.

But if you're serving your app locally in dev then Angular CLI may be loading up lodash as part of the CLI's dependencies.

If your app isn't using lodash directly (search for "from 'lodash" in your project) then you're not going to get it bundled into your final output.